# Every user can edit and delete own comment?

Tags: wordpress, comments, edit

i am making a wordpress theme like eksisozluk.com

users can register and their first role is subscriber. they can only make 10 comments. after that i examine the user's comments and if user profile is enough for the my website, i upgrade role to the editor.

so i want to subscribers and editors can edit and delete their comment, and only edit post content (not post title and not delete it.)

i try the code of the below but nothing changed.

```
$subscriber= get_role('subscriber');
$subscriber->add_cap('edit_comment');
```

Answer (score 0):

try a front end post editor like:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/frontier-post/